# how to install cx_oracle python db driver?

Tags: python, software-installation

I need to install cx_oracle on my pi but I couldn't find arm-specific version or sources. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: There don't seem to be any Debian packages for this. But over at StackOverflow there are instructions on how to build it from source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307479/install-cx-oracle-for-python. Might take a while on the Pi.

Comment: Yes and no. This problem can't be currently solved, because Oracle doesn't support ARM-based platforms.